# NullReferenceException with Assert.That and NunitLite

Tags: nunit

I'm using NunitLite for my unit testing for a Xamarin project.

Environment:

- Windows 8.1 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2012
- Test project class library referencing .NET 4.5
- NunitLite V1.0.0 package from NuGet - contains a build for .NET 4.5
- Running tests using Nunit Test Adapter V1.2 from NuGet

With even the simplest test:

```
[Test]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    Assert.That(1 == 1);
}
```

I'm getting the exception:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.   Source=nunitlite   StackTrace:
>          at NUnit.Framework.Assert.IncrementAssertCount()
>          at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
>          at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Boolean condition)
>          at SportLogger.Tests.Unit.Core.when_using_venue_manager.SimpleTest() in
>        c:\SportLogger\SportLogger.Tests.Unit.Core\CoreTests.cs:line 65   InnerException:

Does anyone have any pointers as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using standard Nunit, not NunitLite. I'm not sure why NunitLite doesn't work in a standard Windows test library.

Bearing in mind that NunitLite is meant to be used (in this context) on the iOS and Android projects, switching to Nunit for the core test project, and NunitLite for the iOS and Android test projects fixed the problem.